# Does the Anti-Bio Beam deal friendly fire?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

If I use the Anti-Bio Beam on my own crew members while boarding an enemy ship, will they take damage?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does 60 damage to crew members of either ship.

From the [FTL Wikia](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Beam_(Weapon)):

I think it is safe to assume your own crew will take damage while boarding. If you have drone bay feel free to go drone boarder crazy.

Tip: If you have anti-bio beam AND boarder drone put your boarder drone in a 2 by 2 room to get more enemy crew in one spot. Then hit that room with anti-bio beam and all 4 will be hit.

Comment: Beam weapons only hit crew whose tiles they touch - I don't think it's possible to hit all 4 tiles in a 2x2 room, but 3 out of 4 is possible. You might  hit all 4 crew if you are very lucky and some of them are on the move as the beam moves through the room.

Comment: You can use the boarder drone to bash away the one crew member your beam doesn't hit. While using the anti-bio beam to hit the squares of the other 3 crew member. You are right although beam only damage the squares they actually touch.